# Route53にネームサーバーを移行後、GoDaddyで購入したOffice365のメールが受信できなくなりました。

Tags: aws, dns, サーバー管理

GoDaddyでドメインを購入し、
かつ、ドメインメールもGoDaddy経由で購入しました。(Office365)

購入当初はメールの送受信が出来ていたのですが、
要件上、AWSのRoute53を使わなくてはいけなくなり、
Route53にネームサーバーを移行しました。

DNSがAWSに移り、ドメインとの紐付けも完了して一段落したのですが、
GoDaddyで購入したOffice365のメールが受信できなくなりました。

但し、送信はできております。

次のような記事を参照して
Office 365 カスタムドメインを追加しRoute 53に各種レコードを設定する方法等を探っているのですが
GoDaddyで購入したためか、ドメイン追加へのリンクが存在しておりません。

[Office 365 カスタムドメインを追加しRoute 53に各種レコードを設定する](http://blog.hrendoh.com/add-custom-domain-to-office365/)

[Office365の管理者ページ、参考キャプチャ](https://gyazo.com/972cc5063794ed2ed49edf447516a9f1?token=bd72c149db06b6a3d89b0e3653fe4f1e)

Office 365のメールは年間契約してしまっったため、可能な限り、こちらを使う方法で、
Route53との接続を行いたいです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: MX レコードはどうなっていますでしょうか？

Comment: MX レコードはRoute53には、設定しておりません。offce365の方では、ドメインの詳細ページがない？ため、MXレコードも取得できないのが現状です。

Comment: https://support.office.com/ja-jp/article/Office-365-%25E3%2581%25AE-DNS-%25E3%2583%25AC%25E3%2582%25B3%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2583%2589%25E3%2581%25AE%25E4%25BD%259C%25E6%2588%2590%25E3%2581%25AB%25E5%25BF%2585%25E8%25A6%2581%25E3%2581%25AA%25E6%2583%2585%25E5%25A0%25B1%25E3%2582%2592%25E5%258F%258E%25E9%259B%2586%25E3%2581%2599%25E3%2582%258B-77f90d4a-dc7f-4f09-8972-c1b03ea85a67?ui=ja-JP&rs=ja-JP&ad=JP

Comment: [ドメイン] ページというのがGoDaddy経由で購入した場合、できないのではないかと推測しております。

Comment: キャプチャ見ましたが、なんか画面が違いますね。Admin centerののURLは「https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/homepage」ですか？

Answer (score 3):

あるドメインに対するメールをどこのメールサーバーに配送するかは、そのネームサーバーからMXレコードで提供する情報です。GoDaddyのネームサーバーを利用していた時は必要なレコードを自動的に追加してくれていただけなので、**ネームサーバーを変更したらそれらを自分で追加しなければいけません**し、さもなくばそのドメイン宛のメールの配送ができなくなります。

そこで本来はOffice365の方で必要なレコードが調べられるはずですが、それが管理画面に出てこないということは、**GoDaddy専用版だから表示していない**、と考えるのが妥当ではないでしょうか。「ドメイン」メニューを含んだ管理画面の例は、例えば公式の「[Office 365 の [ドメイン] ページに移動する - Office 365](https://support.office.com/ja-jp/article/Office-365-%E3%81%AE-%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3-%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AB%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-026af1f2-0e6d-4f2d-9b33-fd147420fac2?ui=ja-JP&rs=ja-JP&ad=JP)」という記事で古い管理センターとして紹介されていますから、見比べてみてください。

理屈上は以前のネームサーバーに登録されていたレコードをRoute53に登録すれば動くと思いますが、今後その内容が変化しても追従することができませんし、ライセンス契約上の問題がある可能性もあります。個人的にも勧めたくない方法ですから、これ以上の説明は避けておきます。

正攻法でなんとかしたいなら、サポート窓口に問い合わせるのがベストです。
「無理です」という回答になるかもしれませんが。

Comment: ドメインに対応するメールサーバの情報はホスト名で指定します。そのホスト名のIPアドレスを解決するのは、そのホスト名のドメインの(別の)DNSサーバの仕事です。Office365であれば、顧客は自分のドメインのDNSにMXレコードとしてMicrosoftの物であるホスト名を指定し、そのホスト名のIPアドレスを解決するのは(顧客ではなく)MicrosoftのDNSサーバになります。

Comment: @suzukis IPアドレスどうのは確かに誤りですね。ここでは当該ドメインのネームサーバが関与している、ということを最低限伝えたかったので、IPアドレスともホスト名とも書かないように修正しました。

Answer (score 2):

1. 権威DNSが正しくRoute53に移っているか
2. Route53で正しくゾーンが作成できているか
3. Office365にドメインの設定が正しくできているか
4. Office365にメールをルーティングするMXレコードが適切に設定できているか

これらを順を追って確認してください。DNSの場合、TTLの影響もありますのでその点も考慮してください。これらができていれば普通は動くはずです。各種コントロールパネルが手順通りに動作しないのであれば、ここで聞くよりそれぞれのサポート窓口に問いあわせた方が確実です。

上記の項目で具体的に何をしたら良いのかわからないとか結果の良否が判断できないのであれば、構築や運用は経験のあるシステムインテグレータに費用を払ってやってもらうことを強くお勧めします。